Jenkins status when retry function is used during automation test
I am using retry listener in one of my test repository, which is running everyday.
In the jenkins we are using TestNG Result plugin  835.v51
In the picture you can see that all test have passed and only 1 test was retried.
Also at the end , when restng-result.xml file is processing , i am getting this message in log
"0.970874% of tests were skipped, which exceeded threshold of 0%. Marking build as UNSTABLE"
Does anyone know, how to make jenkins pipeline status SUCCESS if retry function is used ?
Thank you
enter image description here
fix jenkins status after automation test

If your jenkins job is a pipeline job, just add unstableSkips: 100 in testNG step:
testNG unstableSkips: 100
and If your jenkins job is not a pipeline job, you will find an option to mark build success in advanced section of TestNG result publish post build action:


I know about this parameter UnstableSkips. But i would like to avoid increasing this number as sometimes a skipped test may have signalization an issue with test.
Also i know, that retries test are evaluated as a skipped test.
Thats why i am looking for something else to resolve this problem.
